# Are my basement walls sweating?

Tags: water, basement, foundation, waterproofing

Portions of my basement wall are darker and appear to be wet, but to the touch they are just slightly cooler. I took a few pictures to show. The pattern of the darker areas is strange in some places where it appears.  The 2x4's running along the top where it looks quite wet are dry.

Is this water coming through the walls?
[image: wall 1]
[image: wall 2]
[image: wall 3]

Comment: I'm 99% sure that this is water (humidity).But the pattern is very strange...What I is that thing on top of the wall? Looks like a roof?

Comment: @pythonstarter The OP said it was a basement. I presume those are the joists for the floor above. ;-)

Comment: @Craig yeah that really makes sense. :)))

Comment: Yes those are floor joists :)

Comment: Could it be a difference in temperatures in the wall? Thus the unusual patterns?

Answer (score 2):

Simple test:

Take some clear plastic.  One layer from a large sandwich bag would be ideal.  Tape it securely to the wall at a spot where you're observing the problem.  Make sure you seal **all the way** around the edge of the piece of plastic.  Do this a few different places.

Wait a few days.  Then check the test strips.  If the moisture is on the room side of the plastic, you have a high humidity-condensation problem.  If the moisture is under the layer of plastic, between it and the wall, then you have a moisture-through-the-wall problem, and you should look at your eaves and drainage around the outside of your house...

Comment: I like this answer. I was thinking it is as likely to be condensation as anything else, and hard to say for sure without testing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well im assuming ur under groud and concrete holds moisture and the humidity in the room Along with the florescent lights are making walls sweat or condensate. I'd purchase some very good water sealant and apply it.

Comment: It's actually in the furnace room. Granted we haven't been running it much lately, perhaps that's why. Cooler in the basement than it is outside. ??